# Como eu faço pra buscar dados de um chave estrangeira com laravel de uma relação de muitos pra muitos?

Tags: mysql, laravel, relacionamento

Eu tenho criado duas tabelas, uma de usuários e outra de tarefas e existe uma relação de muitos pra muitos entre elas. Pra isso eu tenho uma terceira tabela dessa relação que informa o id da tarefa e id do usuário. A tabela de tarefas possui 3 chaves estrangeiras, que são o tipo de tarefa, o status da tarefa e o cliente. Eu consegui puxar as tarefas de um usuário mas eu não consegui puxar os dados das chaves estrangeiras, pois eu quero exibir o nome do status, nome do tipo da tarefa e nome do cliente pras tarefas do usuário. Abaixo está a estrutura do banco.

[image: estrutura do banco de dados]

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei a aplicação exata que você quer fazer, mas vou supor que você quer fazer uma listagem, e possui a relação ManyToMany Usuários_Tarefas, na model Usuários você precisa ter declarado a relação:

```
public function tarefas() {
    return $this->hasMany(Tarefas::class);
}
```

e na model Tarefas, você irá fazer a declaração dos usuários e das tabelas as quais ele pertence:

```
public function usuarios() {
    return $this->hasMany(Usuario::class);
}

public function client() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
}

public function status() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Status::class);
}

public function type() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Type::class);
}
```

também seria bom declarar nas models Status, Type e Client, a relação da qual eles tem com tarefas, provavelmente HasMany.

resolvido a questão das relações, digamos que você queira listar as tarefas de todos os usuário sem uma view, com os respectivos dados das tabelas estrangeiras, um exemplo seria:

```
@foreach($usuarios as $usuario) 
    {{ $usuario->name }}
    @foreach($usuario->tarefas as $tarefa)
        {{ $tarefa->title }}
        {{ $tarefa->client->name}}
        {{ $tarefa->type->name}}
        {{ $tarefa->status->name}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

como você pode perceber, eu utilizei a variável declarada na model "Tarefas", por exemplo "client", daí na view ele puxará todos os dados do client, o "name" foi algo que eu estipulei, e dessa maneira ele irá entregar o nome do cliente, daquela tarefa, daquele usuário. Como eu não sei exatamente o que você quer, utilizei um exemplo bem simples, mas que você pode ir trabalhando para entregar a informação que você precisa.